# ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'public'

Tags: solidity

ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'public', I am new to solidity using remix to compile also tried different version.

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
    pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
    struct list{
        string Pan;
        uint age;
        address Address;
        bool Enrolled;
        bool voted;
    } 
    struct candidate_list{
        string Name;
        address Address;
        uint id;
        bool listed;
    }
    address election_officer;
    string public decimal="0";// getting error here
    uint public totalSupply;
    address public founder;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state variables need to be inside of a contract. We can declare structs outside of a contract, but only `constant` variables can be outside of a contract:

With both structs inside of the contract `Ballot`:

```js
contract Ballot {
    struct list{
        string Pan;
        uint age;
        address Address;
        bool Enrolled;
        bool voted;
    } 
    struct candidate_list{
        string Name;
        address Address;
        uint id;
        bool listed;
    }
    address election_officer;
    string public decimal="0"; // Works alright now
    uint public totalSupply;
    address public founder;
}
```

With both structs outside of the contract `Ballot`:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

struct list{
    string Pan;
    uint age;
    address Address;
    bool Enrolled;
    bool voted;
} 
struct candidate_list{
    string Name;
    address Address;
    uint id;
    bool listed;
}

contract Ballot {
    address election_officer;
    string public decimal="0"; // Works alright now
    uint public totalSupply;
    address public founder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared variables out of contract.
So the variables are at the file level.

- Only constant variables are allowed at the file level
- Shouldn't set visibility for variables at the file level. These are public in default.

So the code need be like below

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
struct list{
    string Pan;
    uint age;
    address Address;
    bool Enrolled;
    bool voted;
} 
struct candidate_list{
    string Name;
    address Address;
    uint id;
    bool listed;
}
address constant election_officer = address(0);
string constant decimal = "0";
uint constant totalSupply = 1000e18;
address constant founder = address(0);
```

But I guess what you are trying to do is to use and update these variables in the contract.
So the variables should be declared in the contract.